# adminhtml tag in config.xml file does not work

Tags: magento

I am new to magento and making a custom module and want to work on admin end but after installing extension I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Submitdigital_CustomLogo_Helper_Data' not found in /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/unisport_com/app/Mage.php on line 547
```

After insatalling extension when I clear cashe it give me this error. After somestudy I found that the error is due to this file at path:

```
app/code/local/Submitdigital/CustomLogo/etc/config.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Submitdigital_CustomLogo>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Submitdigital_CustomLogo>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <customlogo>
                <class>Submitdigital_CustomLogo_Helper</class>
            </customlogo>
        </helpers>
        <blocks>
            <customlogo>
                <class>Submitdigital_CustomLogo_Block</class>
            </customlogo>
        </blocks>
        <models>
            <customlogo>
                <class>Submitdigital_CustomLogo_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>customlogo_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </customlogo>
            <customlogo_mysql4>
                <class>Submitdigital_CustomLogo_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <customlogo>
                        <table>customlogo</table>
                    </customlogo>
                </entities>
            </customlogo_mysql4>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <customlogo_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Submitdigital_CustomLogo</module>
                    <class>Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </customlogo_setup>
            <customlogo_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </customlogo_write>
            <customlogo_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </customlogo_read>
        </resources>
    </global>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <admin_customlogo>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Submitdigital_CustomLogo</module>
                    <frontName>admin_customlogo</frontName>
                </args>
            </admin_customlogo>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <menu>
            <customlogo module="customlogo">
                <title>SubmitDigital</title>
                <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                <children>
                    <customlogo module="customlogo">
                        <title>Manage Customlogo</title>
                        <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                        <action>customlogo/adminhtml_customlogo</action>
                    </customlogo>
                </children>
            </customlogo>
        </menu>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <all>
                    <title>Allow Everything</title>
                </all>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <customlogo translate="title" module="customlogo">
                            <title>SubmitDigital</title>
                            <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
                            <children>
                                <customlogo translate="title">
                                    <title>Manage Customlogo</title>
                                    <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                                </customlogo>
                            </children>
                        </customlogo>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <customlogo>
                    <file>customlogo.xml</file>
                </customlogo>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <customlogo>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Submitdigital_CustomLogo</module>
                    <frontName>customlogo</frontName>
                </args>
            </customlogo>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <customlogo>
                    <file>customlogo.xml</file>
                </customlogo>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

all goes well with the file but when I add `<adminhtml>...</adminhtml>` in the file it gives the above error and hence I am not able to see anything at my admin end.

Please Help

here is my customlogo.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
  <customlogo_adminhtml_customlogo_index>
    <reference name="content">
      <block type="customlogo/adminhtml_customlogo" name="customlogo" />
    </reference>
  </customlogo_adminhtml_customlogo_index>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the helper class to fix this issue.

> app/code/local/Submitdigital/CustomLogo/Helper/Data.php

```
class Submitdigital_CustomLogo_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

}
```

You have the following code to call the helper

```
<customlogo module="customlogo">
```

Here

`module`  parameter is used to  **call the helper for translation**.

Comment: remove all `module="customlogo"` in side `<adminhtml>` tag, then check.

Comment: after deleting cashe error is removed now I am able to see my extension but with blank page.

Comment: yes iam doing that. Its taking time... :( will update as it is done. I am not able to see anything at my frontend i.e blank too. Is session is the reason for this also?

Comment: session deletion is taking so much time. So I renamed the session folder but still blank page